# Why image is not displaying in Bootstrap written in phpstorm under laravel blade file?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Apologies if this is an idiotic question: I used the following `src` declaration within an `img` tag to display an image on a `Bootstrap` website in `phpstorm` under a `laravel` blade file: `src="C:\Users\MAHE\Pictures\Wallpapers\photo.jpg"`.

The image does not display; it's just invisible because the mouse pointer is showing the hand symbol when hovered; however, the image displays perfectly when the `src` declaration is:
`src="http://weknowyourdreamz.com/images/apple/apple-02.jpg"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first link is pointing locally (C: drive). Are you using a localhost or displaying it locally or is it live on a server?

**If your website is hosted locally:**

Use a relative path, example: `images/file_01.jpg`

**If your website is live:**

Use a link to an image that is on a server, as the path is meaningless in this context.

EDIT:

(Elaboration on relative paths to give more clarity as per comment)

The location for the relative path would be wherever the file is in relation to the file that you are trying to link from, so you would need to host the file with the site in order to achieve this. The link itself would depend on your file structure, a typical link would read such as: `../images/cat_01.jpg` (the preceding  "/" , "./", "../" represent Root directory, current working directory, and parent directory, respectively).

[This Link](http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/) provides a good summary of Relative vs Absolute paths.

If you cannot achieve this then host the image wherever you can and provide the entire URL for the image. Example `src="http://www.forexample.com/images/cat_01.jpg"`.

As you should now be able to see, this is why the second link works. Your file can actually access this image whereas the first link points to a specific location on a computer - this makes no sense in a web environment.

Comment: can you tell me what can be the relative path in the above context?

Comment: I have added an edit to my answer to hopefully provide further elaboration

Comment: bro, i tried that and now it is showing the broken image symbol

Comment: Which did you try? Need a bit more info I think

Comment: I kept an image in the same folder as the file, and directly put the name with the jpg extension

Comment: have you tried using the prefix "./" to point to the current working directory as per my explanation?

Comment: Can you please provide a url

Comment: its running in my localhost. Can I do that?

Comment: In that case no. I would put it into an 'images' directory and point to it and both ../images/photo.jpg and images/photo.jpg should work, this will avoid any permission issues at root level or similar

Comment: still the broken image logo showing. I a going to suicide now

Comment: Can you bring the image up in a browser directly?

Comment: Yes, I can do it through normal html for the same file.